# Openwhisk and javascript issue

Tags: javascript, openwhisk

I want to do something really simple. I want to find the total sum of all the elements of a JSON object via openwhisk and javascript. However, the following code gives 0 as a result.

```
function sum(params){
        var s=0;
        for(var i=0; i<params.length; i++) s+=params[i];
        return s;
}

function main(params){
        return {payload : sum(params)};
}
```

As an input I have for instance this `{0: 2, 1: 56, 2: 99, 3:12}`
Any suggestions?

Comment: Because params.length does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{0: 2, 1: 56, 2: 99, 3:12}` this is object so, `params.length` is not valid.

Try the array input:

```
[2, 56, 99, 12]
```

Otherwise, loop through the object:

```
function sum(params){
    var s=0;
    for(var key in params) {
      if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        s += parseInt(params[key]);
      }
    }
    return s;
}

function main(params){
    return {payload : sum(params)};
    // params = {0: 2, 1: 56, 2: 99, 3:12}
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid array Sir

Answer (score 3):

More of a JavaScript than an OpenWhisk question, but here you go:

```
function sum(params) {
    return Object.values(params).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);
}

function main(params) {
    return {payload: sum(params)};
}
```

[`Object.values(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) returns an array of all values in the object. [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) aggregates all values of an array into a single value using the aggregation function (`acc + cur` in this case)

Comment: The problem is that openwhisk doesn't support reduce

Comment: You're right, on the default `nodejs` kind (which resolves to `nodejs:6`) those features are indeed not available. They are however, if you use `--kind nodejs:8` when creating the action.

Comment: OpenWhisk does support it if you use Node v8. When creating your action, do: --kind nodejs:8